# TELNET control information

Tags: telnet, rfc

As said in [**RFC 854**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc854):

> A TELNET connection is a Transmission Control Protocol (TCP)
> connection used to transmit data with interspersed TELNET control
> information.

So, what's the TELNET control information? Can you get an example?

Comment: Yes, you can, easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Control information is sent using sequences beginning with the `IAC` code. See the section titled **TELNET COMMAND STRUCTURE** in the RFC.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I have one doubt: Does it mean that client-server communication via telnet is just TCP session?

Comment: Yes, what else would it be?

Comment: _With the current set-up, only the IAC need be doubled to be sent as data_ Why when I sent from TCP server to telnet client 2 bytes of ASCII like this `255,55,55` only last 55 ASCII byte will return to client?

Comment: IAC control sequences aren't sent to the terminal, they're processed by the TELNET program internally.

Comment: What part of "off-topic" is confusing to you? Are you programming a TELNET client or server? If so, please post a question about the code. But I'm not sure why you would bother, it's mostly obsolete. SSH is the common remote login protocol these days.

Answer (score 0):

Telnet control information varies form setting the terminal type, to allowing read-ahead.
Including setting window size and turning on/off of echo.